# Apache FOP Batik transcoder hangs/blocks in java on centos 7?

Tags: spring, apache, centos7, tomcat8, batik

I have a simple web app that's made with spring java. It basically converts an SVG image to a PDF document using the FOP Batik transcoder. The code used is more or less as follows.

Transcoder transcoder = new PDFTranscoder();
TranscoderInput transcoderInput = new TranscoderInput(new FileInputStream(new File("/tmp/test.svg")));
TranscoderOutput transcoderOutput = new TranscoderOutput(new FileOutputStream(new File("/tmp/test.pdf")));
transcoder.transcode(transcoderInput, transcoderOutput);

My problem is that when i deploy the webapp using tomcat 8.5.6 on a centos 7 machine, it always hangs/blocks on the transcoder.transcode line. It works perfectly fine on ubuntu. I know it's not a file's permission issue because it doesn't throw an error. What could be the cause ??

Comment: kugar, please provide heap allocation details for tomcat

Comment: same issue here... does anyone have a solution/update for this?

Comment: I think I found something... this helped me out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50865994/4424934

The issue was Batik Transcoder tried searching for fonts all over the place and never stopped.